# Ghostscript initialization fails with simple Ghost4J sample code

Tags: java, ubuntu, ghostscript, x86-64

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 amd64, Sun JDK 6.0.24 and the default ghostscript package.
Now, I am trying to get the ["Render a PDF document using SimpleRenderer" sample](http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/highlevelapisamples.html) from the [Ghost4J page](http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/highlevelapisamples.html) working.

While the "List fonts of a PDF document using FontAnalyzer" example is working, the SimpleRenderer-sample fails for all PDF that I tried so far with the following error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ghost4j.GhostscriptException: Cannot initialize Ghostscript interpreter. Error code is -20
at net.sf.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:318)
at net.sf.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer.run(SimpleRenderer.java:84)
... 3 more
```

Any advice?

Comment: This most likely comes from the underlying ghostscript installation being broken.  Does it work with the various utilities from the commandline?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well.  Please help!

Comment: Please add Ghostscript and Ghost4J versions to the description.

Answer (score 2):

I asked in a comment for Ghostscript and Ghost4J versions (the latter not so important, since I could still glean what happens from the latest tag 0.4.3).

I downloaded the Ghostscript code from [here](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=summary) and saw from the error code headers file that `-20` means that there was some sort of type error in the C code.

Here is the definition:

```
#define e_typecheck (-20)
```

Please try a different/later version of Ghostscript, or another [variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript#Variants), if possible. Alternatively, let me know what arguments you used to the example code, and host any example PDFs somewhere so we can try it out.